# Why Angular creates project with lower version than the installed version?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the following version information installed on my PC:

```
$ ng --version

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1001.1
@angular-devkit/core         10.1.1
@angular-devkit/schematics   10.1.1
@schematics/angular          10.1.1
@schematics/update           0.1001.1
rxjs                         6.6.2
```

However, although I have Angular 10 installed, when creating a new project via VS Code using the following command, my project version does not seems to be the latest version as on my PC:

```
dotnet new angular
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
cd ClientApp
npm install
```

But in the dependencies, it seems to be @angular/core": "8.2.12" (or maybe it means 8+ that means backward compatible, but I could not be sure):

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "8.2.12",
    "@angular/common": "8.2.12",
    "@angular/compiler": "8.2.12",
    "@angular/core": "8.2.12",
    "@angular/forms": "8.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "8.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-server": "8.2.12",
    "@angular/router": "8.2.12",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "8.1.1",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "core-js": "^3.3.3",
    "jquery": "3.4.1",
    "oidc-client": "^1.9.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
    "zone.js": "0.9.1"
},
```

So, what is the reason for that and what it means? And why are they different? Do I have to upgrade project manually even if I use the latest Angular version while creating an Angular project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you will run `ng new my-app` will create project with last version that you have , but in your case the issue is related with configuration of dotnet , unfortunately I'm not familiar with Dotnet but you could check your configuration

Comment: So, when creating Angular project via dotnet command it may use lower version according to the compatibility of the .NET version installed on the PC. Yes, at least it is good to know that `ng new my-app` command does not use any other version than the installed Angular version when creating project.